# How to know when the model is destoyed automatically by a :dependent => :destroy in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, destroy

I have the following association:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy
  before_destroy :do_some_stuff
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  before_destroy :do_other_stuff
end
```

I would like to know in do_other_stuff if the destruction has been fired by dependent => destroy or not because part of it would/will be done in do_some_stuff

I tried `parent.destroyed?`, `parent.marked_for_destruction?`, `parent.frozen?` but nothing work :/

any ideas?

Comment: I don't think `parent` will exist when the dependent objects are being destroyed. It is already gone.

Comment: The children are destroyed before the parent is destroyed. There will be no flag available on the parent, afaik.

Comment: @tadman is incorrect.  `parent` exists when the dependent object is being destroyed, because the children get destroyed prior to the `parent` getting destroyed.  The order seems to be as follows: `before_destroy` callback is fired on `children` before they get destroyed, `children` then get destroyed, `before_destroy` callback is fired on `parent`, `parent` then lastly gets destroyed.  Can you move the logic of what you're trying to do into the `do_some_stuff` method?

Comment: thanks for comments. Actually, the order is <code>parent.some_stuff</code> then <code>child.do_other_stuff</code> then destroy of <code>child</code> then destroy of <code>parent</code>. The thing to do the logic on do_other_stuff is really crucial and I don't see how to do it elsewhere in the case of <code>destroy</code> is being called only for the child :/. Don't you think that if I put an attribute like <code>being_destroyed?</code> in parent may be a wise idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the association callbacks ( `before_remove` or `after_remove`)

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy, :before_remove => :do_foo

  before_destroy :do_bar

  def do_bar
  end

  def do_foo
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, nice catch.  I ended up with `:dependent => :delete_all` and do the job (logging the destruction) in the `before_destroy` of parent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :children
    before_destroy :some_stuff
    def some_stuff
        children.each do |child|
            child.parent_say_bye
        end
    end
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent
    before_destroy :do_other_stuff
    def parent_say_bye
        #do some stuff
        delete
    end
end
```

Comment: Yep, that could do the trick even if then the <code>:dependent => :destroy</code> is then no necessary. I would be a bit frustrated to do that because then I kind of redo something rails proposes...

Comment: I don't think that this is a good solution, but it works. However thank you for mentioning about `:dependent => :destroy`

Comment: that's why I ended up with `:dependent => :delete_all` and do the job (logging the destruction) in the `before_destroy` of parent